# Is there any example of a set, together with the "sum" operation which is non conmutative?

Tags: abstract-algebra, soft-question

I was wondering if there is any mathematical structure (Im not even sure this is the correct way to name what I have in mind) but basically, any set, together with the operation sum, (I don´t say just a group, since in my ignorance I may be missing some other potential examples of my doubt) which is non conmutative?

Basically, I was thinking about usual operations I use to handle, sum, product or function composition, and with both function composition and product, it is easy to find an example of non conmutative sets (with respect to those operations), however, I wasn't able to think an example for the sum. Is there any? Does it make any sense?

Comment: What is your definition of "sum"?

Comment: Well, that's an excelent question, Im thinking about the different usual sum's I use, for adding numbers, functions, matrices and the other usual mathematical objects. I understand that I can think the "sum" as $+:A\times A \to A$ but I don't know If I have to ask for some other specifical characteristic. But maybe what Im saying is nonsense.

Comment: I think the issue is that what you have in mind about $+$ is not a precise mathematical definition. $+$ can be $\times$ or $\circ$ because "$+$" is just a symbol used to denote a binary operation. For instance, we talk about rings endowed with $+$ and $\cdot$, though the plus and $\cdot$ need not be "actual" $+$ and $\cdot$, consider for instance the endomorphism ring of an Abelian group, or a quotient ring

Comment: ordinal arithmetic is not commutative e.g. $1+\omega\neq \omega +1$

Answer (score 1):

Take the 2-element set $\{a, b\}$ together with the multiplication defined by $aa = ab = a$, $bb = ba = b$. This is actually one of the two smallest examples of a non-commutative [semigroup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semigroup).

If you wish a concrete example, consider the two matrices $a= \begin{pmatrix}  1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ and $b= \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0\\ 1 & 1  \end{pmatrix}$ under the usual product of matrices.

Answer (score 0):

Concatenation "looks like" a sum, but it is not commutative.

Answer (score 0):

In Hatcher's Algebraic Topology book the symbol $+$ is used for the binary operation in $\pi_n(X,A,x_0)$ for $n>1$, where $X$ is a topological space and $A$ is a subspace. Most of the time this operation is commutative, but if $n=2$ it need not be when $A$ has more than one point, and I seem to recall a formula in the book like
$$a+b-a$$
meaning $b$ conjugated by $a$ in a nonabelian relative homotopy group.